# Creating non-scrollable div above scrollabe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

How do i create a Div that is 100% width & height that cannot be scrolled on. However, with a button click that goes to the "next view" which is top:100%; (out of sight) I want the second portion of the website to be scrollable. Sort of like a front-page you could say.

What i'm looking for is more or less a JS that disables scrolling on a portion of the website.

ex of what I want is used on: https://mega.co.nz/. the scrollbars have disappeard on the "front-page"

Comment: you should use custom scroll plugin for that.

Comment: you can disabled scrolling width `overflow:hidden;` and add scrolling to a container using `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:scroll;` @Krunal Panchal is right. What you want have can be done with a plugin, that uses custom javacsript scrollbars. But the handling feels weired in this case imo.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little fiddle with a simple example. All you have to do is manage the .after class on those elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/CXtKC/

```
$('.next').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.screen1').addClass("after");
   $('.screen2').addClass("after");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JS plugin](http://designify.me/tutorials/fullpage-js-create-beautiful-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)

A simple and easy to use plugin to create fullscreen scrolling websites. (also known as single page websites) It allows to create fullscren scrolling websites as well as adding some landscape sliders inside the sections of the site.

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe this works... I'm not sure if I really got it, but could you make a a div 
that contains 2 divs, and in that div you disable the scrolling (overflow:hidden).
The first container div you resize't to width: 100% and height: 100%, and put a button to
scroll down to the second div, and in that second div you can able the scrolling